# Viewing Rails model page works on first view but not subsequent views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

This is using Rails 2.2.2

I have a model that uses the acts_as_flaggable plugin, and on the page I use to display an instance of the model, I list any flags that the model has.

When I start my Rails dev server(mongrel) using the standard script/server command, load the page holding the following code, it loads fine:

```
<% @object.flags.each do |flag| %>
<tr>
<td><%= time_ago_in_words(flag.created_at) %> ago</td>
<td><%= flag.flag %></td>
<td><%= link_to flag.user.login, user_path(flag.user) %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

If I reload the page(and on any subsequent views), I get the following NoMethodError error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.include?
```

If I restart the dev server, the page loads fine again one time then subsequent views yield the same strangeness.

If I remove the line:

```
<td><%= link_to flag.user.login, user_path(flag.user) %></td>
```

The page loads fine and will reload fine from then on.

It seems as if the flaggable plugin is having trouble with the user model for some reason, but then why does it work on the first page load? I also can't seem to repeat the problem using script/console.

--EDIT--

Adding in the stack trace per request. Under normal circumstances I usually can handle this particular error, but the part that is confusing me is why it works the first time.

Here is the error page/trace as it appears to me, I hope this proves to be helpful:

```
NoMethodError in Admin#list_flagged

Showing app/views/admin/list_flagged.html.erb where line #65 raised:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.include?

Extracted source (around line #65):

62:                   <tr>
63:                     <td><%= time_ago_in_words(flag.created_at) %> ago</td>
64:                     <td><%= flag.flag %></td>
65:                     <td><%= link_to flag.user.login, user_path(flag.user) %></td>
66:                   </tr>
67:                 <% end %>

RAILS_ROOT: /dev/trunk
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:142:in `create_time_zone_conversion_attribute?'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:75:in `define_attribute_methods'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:71:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:71:in `define_attribute_methods'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:350:in `respond_to?'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:209:in `method_missing'
app/views/admin/list_flagged.html.erb:65
app/views/admin/list_flagged.html.erb:61
app/views/admin/list_flagged.html.erb:24:in `each'
app/views/admin/list_flagged.html.erb:24
app/views/admin/list_flagged.html.erb:14

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:142:in `create_time_zone_conversion_attribute?'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:75:in `define_attribute_methods'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:71:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:71:in `define_attribute_methods'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:350:in `respond_to?'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:209:in `method_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:359:in `method_missing_without_paginate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:212:in `method_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:212:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:212:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:212:in `method_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:359:in `method_missing_without_paginate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mislav-will_paginate-2.3.6/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:167:in `method_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:313:in `fields_for'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:253:in `form_for'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:39:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:39:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/template.rb:73:in `render_template'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/base.rb:256:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/base.rb:367:in `_render_with_layout'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/base.rb:254:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1174:in `render_for_file'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:896:in `render_without_benchmark'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:8:in `realtime'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:868:in `render_without_benchmark'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:8:in `realtime'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1248:in `default_render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1254:in `perform_action_without_filters'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:136:in `perform_action_without_caching'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/caching/sql_cache.rb:13:in `perform_action'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:8:in `cache'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/caching/sql_cache.rb:12:in `perform_action'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in `process_without_filters'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_without_session_management_support'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/session_management.rb:134:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:392:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:183:in `handle_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:110:in `dispatch_unlocked'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:123:in `dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in `dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:132:in `dispatch_cgi'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:39:in `dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:128:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/servers/mongrel.rb:64
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/server.rb:49
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:142:in `create_time_zone_conversion_attribute?'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:75:in `define_attribute_methods'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:71:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:71:in `define_attribute_methods'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:350:in `respond_to?'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:209:in `method_missing'
app/views/admin/list_flagged.html.erb:65
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:359:in `method_missing_without_paginate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:212:in `method_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:212:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:212:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:212:in `method_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:359:in `method_missing_without_paginate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mislav-will_paginate-2.3.6/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:167:in `method_missing'
app/views/admin/list_flagged.html.erb:61
app/views/admin/list_flagged.html.erb:24:in `each'
app/views/admin/list_flagged.html.erb:24
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:313:in `fields_for'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:253:in `form_for'
app/views/admin/list_flagged.html.erb:14
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:39:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:39:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/template.rb:73:in `render_template'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/base.rb:256:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/base.rb:367:in `_render_with_layout'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/base.rb:254:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1174:in `render_for_file'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:896:in `render_without_benchmark'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:8:in `realtime'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:868:in `render_without_benchmark'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:8:in `realtime'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1248:in `default_render'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1254:in `perform_action_without_filters'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:136:in `perform_action_without_caching'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/caching/sql_cache.rb:13:in `perform_action'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:8:in `cache'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/caching/sql_cache.rb:12:in `perform_action'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in `process_without_filters'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_without_session_management_support'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/session_management.rb:134:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:392:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:183:in `handle_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:110:in `dispatch_unlocked'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:123:in `dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in `dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:132:in `dispatch_cgi'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:39:in `dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:128:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/servers/mongrel.rb:64
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/server.rb:49
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3

Request

Parameters:

None

Show session dump

--- 
:user_id: 1
:last_page: http://localhost:3000/
flash: !map:ActionController::Flash::FlashHash {}

Response

Headers:

{"cookie"=>[],
 "Content-Type"=>"text/html",
 "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"}
```

--EDIT #2--

Well, I've "fixed" it. Despite the fact that there is a belongs_to relation in the Flag model, I added the following code to the Flag model from acts_as_flaggable:

```
def user
  User.find(self.user_id)
end
```

This code does allow the page to load without error whether it is the first time on the page or the Nth.

I would have added this as an answer, but I don't know that I am satisfied with this.

Comment: Without complete stack trace it is very hard to help you.

Comment: sorry hernan, don't have a proper fix for you, but just wanted to add that I've run into the same problem (and resorted to the same "fix") with acts_as_commentable plugin: 
* in one of my views, comment.user _always_ fails
* in a method in one of my models, comment.user only fails when using sqlite. when deployed on postgresql it works. huh?

It's one of those bugs that although mitigated in the short term continues to niggle away. I won't be happy till I've figured out what's up!!

Answer (score 1):

Having experience a similar problem, I'd check your `/config/initializers` directory.  Does it declare some methods or include some modules into the models?  If so, it will happen on first load, but the models will get reloaded on subsequent requests without the initializers running again.

Comment: The initializers looked pretty sane to me. Good idea checking them though. This is definitely a tough nut to crack.

Answer (score 1):

No true fix, but here's a workaround. It has to do with the config.cache_classes setting in the development.rb file.

Change:

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

to...

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

and the problem goes away.

Not a great solution, but it seems to have been around since 2.2.2 (I'm on 2.3.12).

Lots of [background and a possible patch here](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1339-arbase-should-not-be-nuking-its-children-just-because-it-lost-interest).

This was my [first clue](http://www.theirishpenguin.com/2009/01/22/bug-of-the-day-nilinclude-error-with-create_time_zone_conversion_attribute/).

Answer (score 0):

That means that you have a nil object where you expected a real object.  It sounds like its crashing somewhere in the internals of your plugin.  Look at the stack trace and see if you can pinpoint where this is ocurring in your code, then wrap some debugging printi outs around it to check if your objects are nil when they shouldn't be.

Without knowing how that plugin works, don't think we can help more.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it doesn't fail the first time it loads. It works fine once, but if you reload it fails. It is easy to see what is the nil object, but it isn't nil on the first viewing of the page.

Comment: This can happen if some code is set to load when the app boots, but development mode reloads classes and doesn't reload this code.  Nothing in the code you post here causes this behaviour.  This can happen with plugins that aren't written right, since rails loads plugins at server launch only.

Comment: Very good. Thanks for this insight! I think the acts_as_flaggable plugin may be a little long in the tooth for Rails 2.2.2. I put in a little bit of a hack to fix it. I'm not terribly happy with it, but the flagging is not too important.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a heresy in the rails world but install netbeans and use their debugging tools to take a look at what is happening.  You can put breakpoints in the html.  It's pretty impressive (though very very slow).